# jQuery export to Excel, include html th rows

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, export-to-csv

I have the fiddle, modified from another forum that exports an html table to CSV with jQuery. This works perfectly however I cannot get it to include the table header rows.

The fiddle is at:
http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/480/

I have messed around with the below syntax without any luck:

```
var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),
```

is it something to do with:

```
$cols = $row.find('td');
```

So I am looking for output to include headings, not just normal table rows.

complete script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),


            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), 
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), 
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace('"', '""'); 
                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
        });
    }


    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple small changes:

```
var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td,th)'),
```

and

```
$cols = $row.find('td,th');
```

Comment: champion thank you. I was trying tr:has(td), tr:has(th). Thanks again, appreciated.

Comment: Yup that worked - I am using it in my project now 

http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/2960/   <<-- working copy