# How to include <th> row in export html table data?

Tags: jquery, html

I used following plugins to export table data in XLS and WORD. But when I export table data it not includes table headings row. So is there any way to include  field in exported data.

```
<li>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"> 
<img src='icons/xls.png' width='24px'> XLS
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'doc',escape:'false'});"> 
<img src='icons/word.png' width='24px'> Word
</a>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tableExport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

HTML Table:

```
<table class="draw_table" id="datawtable" border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a href="disdept.php?sort_element=dept_name&sort_type=<?php echo 
                    ($sort_element == "dept_name"  && $sort_type == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"; ?>">Department
                    <?php if ($sort_element == "dept_name" ) {  if($sort_type == "desc" ) { ?>
                    <img class="sorting" src="images2/downarrow.png" alt="asc">
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <img class="sorting" src="images2/uparrow.png" alt="desc">
                    <?php } } ?>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th >Description</th>
            <th >Options</th>
       </tr>
```

Comment: @jameslafferty: i've seen your solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216495/jquery-export-to-excel-include-html-th-rows?rq=1 Can you please see also this?

Comment: @Rohit Arora: Can you help me on this.

Comment: I think @Sachin is right , You have not followed the HTML structure because adding th's code is already there in plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is correct but you are missing `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags. Your Html should be like this below , You should add  tag in headers and `<tbody>` tag for other rows. Hope this makes you more clear about it :

```
<table class="draw_table" id="datawtable" border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <thead>  // Here we have added a <thead> tag (For headers)
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a href="disdept.php?sort_element=dept_name&sort_type=<?php echo 
                    ($sort_element == "dept_name"  && $sort_type == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"; ?>">Department
                    <?php if ($sort_element == "dept_name" ) {  if($sort_type == "desc" ) { ?>
                    <img class="sorting" src="images2/downarrow.png" alt="asc">
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <img class="sorting" src="images2/uparrow.png" alt="desc">
                    <?php } } ?>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th >Description</th>
            <th >Options</th>
       </tr>
</thead>
   <tbody> // Here we have added a <tbody> tag
     <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Because according to the code in plugin, Its selector looks for `<thead>` , then `<tr>` and then `<th>` for headers and `<tbody>` , then `<tr>` and then `<td>` for data rows.

EDIT 1:

To ignore any of your column, Just pass its index in ignoreColumn parameter like this:

```
$('#tableID').tableExport({
    type:'pdf',
    escape:'false',
    ignoreColumn: [2,3]  // here i have ignored 2nd and 3rd column
});
```

Comment: Thanks champ..! But again I've problem is that I don't want to include 'Options' column and as I'm using this plugin in other tables also some tables don't have 'Option' field so how to achieve this. I also trying for this but from yours also helpful.

Comment: Welcome , So you want to ignore any column ? Check out my new edit. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In tableexport.js below line includes table heading in excel and msword, so there is nothing wrong in tableexport.js

```
 $(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function () {
                    excel += "<tr>";
                    $(this).find('th').each(function (index, data) {
                        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                            if (defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1) {
                                excel += "<td>" + parseString($(this)) + "</td>";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    excel += '</tr>';

                });
```

**Please make sure your html must follow below HTML structure**

```
<table id="tbData" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="tbData_info">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>  Column name 1</th>
                                            <th>Company Name 2
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                              Column name 3
                                            </th>
                                            <th>Column name 4</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody >
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: please tell me whats going wrong with my HTML table, see my edited question.